# why the check engine light on 75 mph speed?

Tags: toyota, cel, corolla

My car is Toyota Corolla 2011.   CEL lights at 75 mph.

I pulled code p02757. There no other thing wrong. The car is running satisfactory, this check lamp is the only trouble.

Comment: Torque converter issue... http://www.autocodes.com/search_codes.php?q=2757

Answer (score 10):

**A P2757 DTC is a torque converter clutch solenoid valve issue**

The valve engages a torque converter at higher speeds to lock your transmission and engine at a 1:1 ratio.  This engagement, obviously, only happens at higher speeds for fuel saving.

Causes include;

- Dirty transmission fluid
- Faulty line pressure solenoid valve SLU
- Line pressure solenoid valve SLU harness is open or shorted
- Line pressure solenoid valve SLU circuit poor electrical connection
- Torque converter clutch
- Valve body is blocked

[**Link to Additional Information**](http://www.autocodes.com/p2757_toyota.html)